# Compiling C Project error for "-std=gnu90"

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, cygwin

I'm trying to cross compile from Windows 7 using Cywin, GCC, Eclipse, and OpenOCD to load the program onto an ARM microcontroller.  I keep getting issues though, when trying to build my project, whether I'm using Eclipse or a Cygwin Terminal.  From the terminal, I get this error:

cc1.exe: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=gnu90"

Could this be fixed by downloading another package from Cygwin?  Anyone know a solution to this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The option you're looking for is probably `-std=gnu89`

Recent versions of GCC accept both `-std=gnu89` and `-std=gnu90` but version 4.4 and earlier  only accepted `89`.

The standard version supported by GCC is commonly known as ANSI C (or C89 because the ANSI standard was ratified in 1989) or ISO C90 (because the ISO re-published the same document in 1990), and so the corresponding option is sometimes spelled `-std=c89` and sometimes `-std=c90` or also `-std=iso9899:1990` for people who want to be really verbose!